# What does M3 stand for in the Clarivoyant challenge?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

What does M3 stand for in the Clarivoyant challenge?

During the Systems Jammed mission, destroying the Electrical Fuse Box before the quest tells me, to, completes the challenge. The challenge's text is:

"Disable the forcefield protecting the second M3 unit before receiving the objective to do so."

But what does "M3" stand for? Is it explained in one of the previous games and I forgot?

Comment: No, as far as I remember the name "M3" was never used in the mission transcript. The only reference I see is that Concordia and lots of the other locations are abanoned Dahl facilities. Dahl also seems to produce the Assault Rifle Ammunition that appear in a camouflaged clip box with "M3 ball" printed on. But the "M3 unit" lacks of an explanation.